# Extract table from the website using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape text from table they will give me data but they will not given me data in these format shown in pic[image]

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request




class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'book'
    start_urls = ['https://blogsrl.it/gb/4-no-food']
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h3/a/@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        rows=response.xpath("//dl[@class='data-sheet']")
        details={}
        for row in rows:
            key = row.xpath('.//dt//text()').get(default='').strip()
            value=row.xpath('.//dd/text()').getall()
            value = ''.join(value).strip()
            details[key] = value
        yield details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `parse_book` callback, the variable `rows` does not return a list but a single element so you can't loop over it. You need to loop over either the row names or the row values. See below snippet on how you can loop over the row names.

```py
def parse_book(self, response):
    rows=response.xpath("//dl[@class='data-sheet']/dt")
    details={}
    for row in rows:
        key = row.xpath("./text()").get()
        value=row.xpath("./following-sibling::dd/text()").get()
        details[key] = value
    yield details
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your XPATH. Your XPATH will not return you a list instead it will return the string since it's only targeting 1 element.

Perhaps try

```
rows=response.xpath("//dl[@class='data-sheet']//dt | //dl[@class='data-sheet']//dd ")
```

Comment: it will give me nothing

Comment: `"//dl[@class='data-sheet']"` this XPath doesn't return a list so you can't loop over it. You need to update it.